# MiKTeX’s LuaLaTeX and minitoc: "I can't write on file ...mtc"

Tags: table-of-contents, errors, luatex, miktex, minitoc

When compiling the code below with LuaLaTeX I get the error: "I can't write on file 'test.mtc'". Any ideas on how to resolve this? (Btw, the file test.mtc is there and contains the word "Contents")

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[tight]{minitoc}
\dominitoc[n]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\minitoc
\lipsum
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\subsection{Test}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Test}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're allowed to write files in the working directory? I have no problem with the example. What OS are you using?

Comment: Window XP 64bit. It works with pdflatex but not with lualatex... And I can write files in the working directory.

Comment: The same (pdfLaTeX yay, LuaLaTeX nay) happens to me with MiKTeX 2.9 on Win7-64, but not with TeX Live 2012.

Comment: I'm also using MiKTeX 2.9 (with TeXnicCenter).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a lonely `\closein\@inputcheck\relax` in minitoc.sty which imho belongs in the definition above it:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[tight]{minitoc}

\makeatletter
\def\mtc@CkFile#1{%
  \@mtc@LItrue\@mtc@FEtrue
  \if@mtc@checkfiles
  \IfFileExists{#1}{%
    \immediate\openin\@inputcheck #1\relax
    \mtc@While{}{\if@mtc@LI\relax}{\mtc@Body}\mtc@EndWhile
    %
    }%
   {\@mtc@FEtrue}%
  \else
   \@mtc@FEfalse%
  \fi
  \closein\@inputcheck\relax}%moved in the definition
\makeatother  

\dominitoc[n]
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
\minitoc
\lipsum
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\subsection{Test}
\lipsum
\subsubsection{Test}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrike! One should choose Latex for this community alone.

Comment: It's quite funny that only MiKTeX's LuaLaTeX chokes on this. The example runs well on my machine. Of course `\immediate` before `\openin` is superfluous.

Comment: @egreg: It works for me with TL too. But as I realized as I looked into this luatex bug http://tracker.luatex.org/view.php?id=827 there are slight differences regarding openin between the various engines and systems so I knew where to look.